# Shell function or Python function to parse the ref value and text substitution

Tags: regex, text, substitution

I'm working on passing few variables list from python to shell script.
The technique  I plan to use is very simple
I execute the python file  to print all variables to a log/text file

The shell script looks at the log file to get the list of variables and substitutes the value

Example

ref.log file has the following contents

```
ref_var1 = '(1,2,3)'
ref_var2 = "('a','b','c')"
```

shell script has following sql code

```
select emp_id, name, join_date
from emp.employees
where name in $ref_var1 or 
emp_id in $ref_var2
```

I want to see if a generic shell function can be developed, where the log file is scanned and the variable values are parsed and consumed by the sql logic

I have lists, strings, dates that  I want to write to the log file and provide that to the shell

Thanks
PMV

Comment: Sounds like you want a prepared statement, not a regex.

Comment: if you need a regex... [is this](https://regex101.com/r/jS2kE8/1) ok?

Comment: @pvg - how do i generate a prepared statement

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello: How do I use the regex function? I did not understand the link. My intent is to parametrize the list so that  I can just call the parameter in the script

Comment: Just google up the db access tutorial for python/your db. Almost all of them use a standard interface which includes facilities for generating sql statements and binding values to them programmatically and safely.

Comment: @pmv The db that i work with is not listed in the python db api.

Comment: I clarified the context in which I want to use regex/text manipulation functions

Comment: That sounds like `. ref.log` in the shell script. But what does this have to do with regex substitution?

Comment: Hi. I was thinking Regex is a possible solution . But if there are more elegant n direct solutions, can u please provide an answer